# SQL Triggers vs server side queries

Tags: sql, database, triggers, webserver, sql-update

Case: I have a table `T1` keeping records of submissions through a form. On updates to the records on this table, I want to insert a row to table `T2`.

For this case, how would the performance of the following scenarios compare?

Scenario A: An `AFTER UPDATE ON T1` trigger builds and inserts the relevant row. Since `T1` has no references to `T2`, this would be okay.

Scenario B: Server side service layer (PHP, python, whatever) inserts the relevant row after making the update.

Scenario C: This would be stored procedures, but there are many comparisons of SPs and triggers, so you don't have to include them.

Comment: It can be pain to find bugs in triggers as they can obfuscate the information. I'd go for procedures if your situation allows (easier to test for one thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the choice between triggers and python, I would choose triggers.  Triggers on your data ensure that T2 contains a record for T1 no matter how the data is inserted, rather than relying on the application, thus ensuring the **integrity** of your data. If you add another application which adds records to T1, with triggers, T2 still gets records inserted.

I don't know why you discount stored procedures though, nor where you get the idea that triggers are faster or "more suited to the nature of a database server"

Comment: Thank you. As Joe mentioned as well, integrity is a very important concern and triggers can eliminate many risks.

Comment: As for the ideas I got, that's mostly from what I read here on SO and a few other places in 5 minutes or so. Saying "I learned that (...)" might have been a little too strong, yes.

Answer (score 4):

I'm really not a fan of triggers. The problem is that they are, by their nature, side effects, and as such tend to be hidden and not obvious to future maintainers of your system. They lead to mistaken code later. Unless you have specific data showing a performance bottleneck of this specific use case, I'd much prefer to see either stored procedure or a "PHP, python, whatever" **service layer** that handles all access to the database. Never lose sight of the fact that *correctness trumps performance*.

Comment: Thanks and yes, doing the job through a service layer was what I meant. The last three words make it very (not overly) simple though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that data is always and only updated in `T1` through your application, I'd vote for doing it in code (PHP/Python or stored procedure). If there's any chance that data can ever be updated another way (a DBA writing a query, perhaps?), then go with the trigger to guarantee you get the consistent results you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out that guaranteeing the update is through the service layer is an important concern.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of using triggers and/or store procedures your sql code is pre-compiled and optimized.  I am doubtful there is a significant performance advantage.  As others have noted, triggers could result in accidental performance issues when updating multiple records on a table, or create difficult to manage update chains.

You will have a much easier time refactoring and maintaining stored procedures than chains of triggers.